# Netsuite: Is there a way to get a value in Netsuite Customer Page > Financial Section > AR Aging Balance

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I wish to get the value in the field as below but no luck.
The way I retrieve the code is as below.

```
var parentid = nlapiLookupField('customer', customerid, 'parent');
var recParent = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', parentid);

var recConsoAging4 = parseFloat(recParent.getFieldValue('consolaging4'));
```

I tried to search in Netsuite record browser and seems like all these fields are not available.
But when i navigate to Netsuite schema browser all these fields are there.

Any help? Thanks.

[[image: Screenshot of Financial Segment in Customer Master: Consolidated AR Aging Balance]
[image: Screenshot of Field Help of Consolidated AR Aging Balance]

Comment: While not always entirely true, as a general rule if a field is not listed in the Records Browser, it is not available to SuiteScript. In this case, it doesn't look like any of the aging fields are available to SuiteScript, but they are available to SuiteTalk (SOAP Web Services API). That probably doesn't help you get what you need, but I don't know of any workaround.

Comment: thanks eric for your note. At least now I know those that are not listed in Record Browser is not available in SuiteScript. Thanks. :)